# How to create outline text with a solid interior in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context, context-mkiv

Following the instructions for `\definespotcolor` at the [ConTeXt Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definespotcolor), I created some outlined text:

```
\defineeffect[outline][alternative=outer,rulethickness=.25pt]
\starttext
    \starteffect[outline]
        \ssa This text appears as an outline.
    \stopeffect
\stoptext
```

I found though, this makes text with a black outline and a transparent interior, so when the page has a background image, the background text shows through. How can I create white text with a black outline?

Comment: Wrap it around a `framed` or `backgroundtext` that has a white backgroundcolor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s a solution using
[overlays](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Overlays):

[image: overlay demo]

```
% macros=mkvi

\definetextbackground [dark] [backgroundcolor=darkblue]

\defineeffect [outline] [
  alternative=outer,
  rulethickness=.25pt,
]

\definecolor [outlinedtext.color.fill]    [red]
\definecolor [outlinedtext.color.outline] [white]

\def\filledoutline#1{%
  \startoverlay
    {\directcolored[outlinedtext.color.fill]%
     #1}
    {\directcolored[outlinedtext.color.outline]%
     \starteffect[outline]#1\stopeffect}%
  \stopoverlay%
}

\starttext
  before
  \endgraf
  \starttextbackground[dark]%
    \filledoutline{\ssa This text appears as an outline.}
  \stoptextbackground
  \endgraf
  after
\stoptext
```

PS: For a more sophisticated approach see the [metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf), section 8.6: *Outline fonts* (grep for *graphictext*).

Comment: Note that the MetaFun method is *much* slower than the ConTeXt method.